# How to put hamburger menu button on top of Appbar and Drawer in mui react?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I tried changing the z-index of my custom hamburger menu button through CSS to 1250 because the z-indexes of AppBar and Drawer respectively are 1100 and 1200, but it didn't work.

Here is the JSX:

```
    <AppBar position='sticky'>
          <Container maxWidth='xl'>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Box>
                            <label className='menu_container' htmlFor='check'>  // this is my custom menu button container
                                    <input
                                        type='checkbox'
                                        id='check'
                                        checked={menuOpen}
                                        onChange={() => {
                                            setMenuOpen(prev => !prev)
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <span></span>
                                    <span></span>
                                    <span></span>
                            </label>
                            <Drawer
                                anchor='left'
                                open={menuOpen}
                                onClose={() => setMenuOpen(false)}
                            >
                                hello world from drawer
                            </Drawer>
                        </Box>
                    </Toolbar>
         </Container>
    </AppBar>
```

CSS:

```
.menu_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1250;
}
```

I want result like this:

[When menu is close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX9Oi.png)

[When menu is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJE3Z.png)

Comment: Why don't you use the collapse and menu components?

I just opened mui docs and it seems that there is a component for almost any thing that you can think about...

https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/overview/

Comment: I am actually new to mui, I am builiding my portfolio site for learning it and I personally chosen drawer for my menu over menu component and I don't know about collapse component now, I will check it out.